# How to pass tuple as parameters of a function

Tags: python, list, function, function-pointers, tuples

I have a tuple containing tuples.

```
EVENT_MAPPING = (
    (func1, (paramA1, paramA2, paramA3)),
    (func2, (paramB1)),
    (func3, (paramC1, paramC2)),
)
```

I iterate over the first tuple. And I want to call the function contained in the first param with args in the second param plus other param. For example, for the first tuple :

```
func1(origin, paramA1, paramA2, paramA3)
```

If their is no the "origin" param, I can have a call thanks to :

```
args[0](args[1])
```

But with the extra param ("origin"), I can't do things like that.
I found a way to do it but it is heavy :

```
call = tuple(list(args[1]).insert(0,origin))
args[0](call)
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this, probably:

```
for func, args in EVENT_MAPPING:
  func(*args)
```

The * extracts (expand) the inner tuple and they are passed to the function as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
for func, args in EVENT_MAPPING:
    func(origin, *args)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the origin to the args, something like this should work:

```
for func, args in EVENT_MAPPING:
    func(*(origin,)+args)
```